# How to read ::after attributes of a radio button element using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I have been trying to read the content inside an html tag which has features like ::before and ::after using selenium webdriver (Java), but I'm having hard time to read those contents since they are dynamic.

For example, In the below HTML code,

```html
<label class="radio radio-label-horizontal control-label" for="id_Fruit_1">
  <input value="Banana" name="Fruit" id="id_Fruit_1" data-field-name="Choices" data-field-type="Structured" tabindex="2" type="radio">
  <span class="radio-label">
  ::before
  Banana
  ::after
  </span>
</label>
```

That's a code snippet for a radio button which is selected, but when I switch the radio button to another choice, it simply removed ::after from the "span" element, and it did not make any change to the "input" element.

But when I did the below java selenium code, I only see 'Banana', and I was expecting to get '::before Banana ::after'

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".radio-label")).getText();
```

Can you please explain how I can find out whether my radio button is checked or not using selenium?

Answer (score 0):

You can isSelected() method to figure out whether radio button is selected or not.

List radioBtn = driver.findElements();
boolean selected=false;
selected=radioBtn.get(0).isSelected() will return true/false whether the button is selected or not.
if(selected)
//perform actions

Answer (score 0):

You can only get the text passed into your application not the HTML tags like following and ancestors